# Read text file and display part of line

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I'm creating a hit counter.
The script that registers that the visitor was there creates a .txt file like this

```
 IP Adress:127.0.0.1

 Timestamp:1400602795

 User Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36

 Times visited:1
```

I want to be able to got information like timestamp and times visited.
One way i'd like to do this is to create an array seperated by ":".

I tried to create the array, But for some reason "Times Visited" does not get included in       the array. Here is the code from that attempt:

```
$fileResource = @fopen("hits/".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].".txt","r");
$fileContent = @fread($fileResource,100000);

$array = preg_match_all("/(.*):(.*)\\n/i",$fileContent,$fileMatches);
//0 = IP
//1 = Timestamp
//2 = User Agent
//3 = Times Visited
echo $fileMatches[0][3];
```

this is the output when i try print_r($fileMatches)

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IP Adress:127.0.0.1

```
        [1] => Timestamp:1400604101

        [2] => User Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => IP Adress
        [1] => Timestamp
        [2] => User Agent
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 127.0.0.1
        [1] => 1400604101
        [2] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
    )

)
```

Comment: Please show some of the ways you have tried to do this. `preg_match_all` is the way to do this. Just don't forget to add multiline switch for regexp.

Comment: something like this should work `|([^:.+]):([^:.+])\n|s`. Not sure about lazyness, and also have to check for new-line which should stop regexp match.

Comment: Loop through each line, find first `:` (use `strpos()`), get everything before and after (use `substr()`) and create your array. (Use `trim()` to strip whitespace.)

Comment: I've edited the post and added some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already read the entire contents of the file into a string, you could use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) twice like this:

```
$s = <<<EOT
IP Address:127.0.0.1

Timestamp:1400602795

User Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36

Times visited:1
EOT;

$arr = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $s) as $line) {    
    if (trim($line) !== '') { // check for empty line
        list($key, $value) = explode(':', $line);   
        $arr[$key] = trim($value);
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Which creates an array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [IP Address] => 127.0.0.1 
    [Timestamp] => 1400602795 
    [User Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36 
    [Times visited] => 1 
)
```

Alternatively, instead of using `fread` you could use `fgets` to read each line one by one, and replace the `foreach` loop with something like `while (fgets($fileResource))`

Comment: Just a quick question, What does the <<<EOT thing do?

Comment: @robin00212 I wrote the sample input with a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). It's just a way of writing a multi-line string. The `EOT` could be any other token like `<<<ENDOFSTRING`, it's just a way of identifying the end of the string.